# Parametrizing external xml file in NAnt

Tags: nant

In my build file, one of the build steps that I'm using is as follows:

```
  <target name="BuildMsDeployPackage" depends="StageForMsDeployPackaging">
    <exec program="${msdeploy.exe}"
          workingdir="${buildDirectory}"
          verbose="true"
          commandline="
           -verb:sync 
           -source:manifest=${currentWorkingDirectory}\${sourceManifest} 
           -dest:package=${publishDirectory}\${webapp.artifact.zip}"/>
```

Here, I'm using MSDeploy to create a package which can later be deployed. The source is in the form of a manifest file. The contents of the manifest file are as follows:

```
<MSDeploy.iisApp> 
    <iisapp path="C:\test" />
    <setAcl path="C:\test\dirOne" setAclAccess="Write" setAclUser="xyz"/>
    <setAcl path="C:\test\dirTwo" setAclAccess="Write" setAclUser="abc"/>
</MSDeploy.iisApp>
```

The paths that I'm using for iisapp and setAcl are hard coded as is evident. I want to be able to specify these in terms the directory where my build file is located (the current working directory).

Is it possible to do this through NAnt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understood your question, you would like to edit the manifest file. Since it is plain XML you could use NAnt's [`<xmlpoke>`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/xmlpoke.html) task for that. Specify the appropriate path attribute via XPath and set it to your build path. You can retrieve the path of your build file with NAnt function [`project::get-buildfile-path`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/functions/project.get-buildfile-path%28%29.html).